Gemini-1.5-pro Node JS API: Error when send an image "Base64 decoding failed"
I am building a chat app with Gemini 1.5 pro Node JS API, when I try to send a message with an image I get this error:
{
field: 'contents[0].parts[2].inline_data.data',
description: `Invalid value at 'contents[0].parts[2].inline_data.data' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAWRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAAAAAAD/7QAwUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAABMcAnQAB1BpY29DVEYcA...The rest of the base64 data

NOTE: The error prints a big chunk of the base64 data in the terminal, so i can't get all the way up to the beggining of the error that's why you're seeing parts[2] instead of parts[1].
Here is the code:
if (msg.attachments.size > 0) {
  let imageParts = [];
  let index = 1;

  msg.attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
    var request = require("request").defaults({ encoding: null });

    let image;

    request.get(attachment.url, async function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        image = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + Buffer.from(body).toString("base64");
        var mimeType = attachment.contentType;
        imageParts.push({
          inlineData: {
            data: image,
            mimeType,
          },
        });

        if (msg.attachments.size === index) {
          const generatedContent = await model.generateContent([
            msg.content,
            ...imageParts,
          ]);

          msg.reply(generatedContent.response.text());
        } else {
          index++;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

